# FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters Empty

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I am passing parameters to flex application as below but it shows empty always .

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="100%" height="100%" id="metaplayer">
                <param name="movie" value="multicastplayer.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
                    <param name="group" value="8155" />
                    <param name="password" value="8155" />
                    <param name="type" value="2" />

                    <param name="streamname" value="8155" />
</object>
```

Accessing it from flex shows empty either of this ways. WriteText is just my function that shows variables in a textbox.

```
writeText(mx.core.Application.application.parameters.group);
                for (var i:String in FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters) {
                    writeText( i + ":" + FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters[i] + "\n");
                }
```

Comment: When are you accessing it?  Could it be before the Application is full initialized; meaning FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication is still null?

Comment: @www.Flextras.com I am accessing it on applicationComplete="init()"

Comment: You are defining the params in a wrong way. You need to specify flashvars as param. See @ZNL -M's answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it works fine with this syntax (passing the arguments through the flasVars" param name):

```
<param name="flashVars" value="locale=${language}&localeFallback=en_US" />
```

And then in my flex:

```
 var parameters:Object = Application(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication).parameters;

 if (parameters.locale) {
     locale = parameters.locale;
 }
```

You can find the official documentation about that on the official web site: http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/pass-variables-swfs-flashvars.html

BTW, you can/should use [swfObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to generate this piece of HTML code. It handles properly passing the parameters to the SWF.

HIH